# How Users can call a SAP module, should they Log in?

Tags: abap, sap-basis

I have created an SAP module for online recrutement exams that requires from candidates to log in to take their exams .. everything works fine but I have no idea how to do the "log in" part where users can log in and take their exams directly. Do I have to create SAP accounts for them or what exactly ?

I am totally a beginner, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You're not even telling us what UI technology you chose - but basically, unless you want to explicitly violate licensing agreements, you need a named SAP user for every business user.